# Table view dates descending order swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, tableview, filtering

Hi I write the following code in tableview cell for row at indexPath method.
I wan to display the data based on the dates in descending order.

Any one please help to me.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pickupsTableViewCell", for: indexPath)as! pickupsTableViewCell

        if let data = getinvoice, data.count > 0 , data.count > indexPath.row
        {
            let model = getinvoice[indexPath.row]

            if let pickupdate = model.pickupDate
            {
                let datefrmt = pickupdate.convertFormatOfDate(originalFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd", destinationFormat: "dd")
                let mnthfrmt = pickupdate.convertFormatOfDate(originalFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd", destinationFormat: "MMM")
                cell.pickuptbldate.text = datefrmt
                cell.pickuptblmnth.text = mnthfrmt?.uppercased()
            }

            if let cardlastnumbers = model.last4
            {
                cell.pickuptblcardnumber.text = ". . . . " + cardlastnumbers
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort data and compare date by following method. But do it before `cellForRow` method.

```
self.getinvoice.sort(by: {
    $0.pickupDate ?? Date() < $1.pickupDate ?? Date()
})
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: Is `pickupDate` string type ?

Comment: Can you please share model? So people can help you.

Comment: if let order = invoicearr[0].orderDetail
                                {
                                    self.errormessagelbl.isHidden = true
                                    self.orderdeta = order
                                }
                                self.getinvoice = invoicearr
                                
                                
                                self.pickupstableview.reloadData()

Comment: class GetInvoice : Mappable{

    var userRewards : UserRewar!
    var orderDetail : [OrderDetail]!
    var calculatedTax : String?
    var cardType : String?
    var chargeTotal : String?
    var credit : String?
    var discount : String?
    var feedback : String?
    var itemCount : Int?
    var last4 : String?
    var orderDate : String?
    var orderID : Int?
    var paymentID : String?
    var pickupDate : String?

Comment: And which format of date is available in `pickupDate`?